# how to add association between models from a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have events and users. On the event show page I want to have a button that is "attend." I want to take the current_user and add an association to the current event therefore making the user "attend" the event.

I have an attend event method in the user model as follows:

```
def attend!(id)
  current_user.events << event.find_by_id(id)
end
```

in the event#show page I have the following form but I don't think i'm doing it right:

```
<%= form_for @event.users.attend(:id) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :id %>
  <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Attend Event" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I'm just not quite sure how I do the association...which I have already setup properly. In the console, I do this and it works:

```
@user.events << @event
```

this adds an association to that user and event that the user is attending the event. This is properly setup and works. The thing I'm confused about is how to add a button on the event view page.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead to add comments to SpyrosP's answer, I'll just write it in my own answer:

You should first create route for attending on event:

```
# in routes.rb
# I assume you have something like this single line below, just add member block with attend
resources :events do
  member do
    post :attend
  end
end
```

Then in your `EventsController` create action:

```
dev attend
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  current_user.events << @event
  redirect_to @event
end
```

And in your view you should create button:

```
<%= button_to 'Attend Event', attend_event_path(@event.id), :method => :post %>
```

Comment: I will try this when I get home. Currently, I don't have that member do thing. All I have is match '/attend' => 'events#attend' or something like that. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, because your attend path doesn't containt any reference to event you want user to attend. You need to pass this as param (just add hash to your attend_path call in view) or create path which contains this event id inside, just like I provided. My solution creates another action for your event, and wen you post to it, you automatically have event's id in your controller, plus your code is inside events controller (its still about event, not user)

Comment: You have to remember, that Rails only generate HTML (or JS), but there is no magic to join your views to actions, it's just request-response cycle. That's why your example doesn't work - you call attend while you *generate* your view, not pass this code to client-side and when he submits form then this code is run.

Comment: Seems I have a lot to learn still. Initially, I had a hash ":id => @event.id" and I thought that would work but didn't. I'm stil a little confused why that wouldn't work since you are saying it should have but I will try it your way this time.

Comment: First check how your generated html looks like (with Firebug for Firefox, Opera Dragonfly or Chrome Inspector you can right-click on element and select Inspect element). You can check what is send in Network tab in Firebug/Dragnofly/Inspector too. And last thing - on server you can put `logger.info params.inspect` to check which params are passed to your action. The rest is as if you run your code in rails console with provided variables.

Answer (score 2):

It should be like (i leave out css for simplicity) :

```
<%= form_for Event.new do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Attend Event" %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT :

Since you look to add current user to a particular event, you can just have a

```
<%= button_to 'Attend Event', your_path, :id => .., :method => :post %>
```

with an id parameter of the @event.

When the user posts, your controller actions gets the event id from params[:id], gets the actual event and users your method to associate with the current user.

SECOND EDIT:

Your_path refers to a named route or if you don't use named routes, something like :

```
:controller => 'users', :action => 'attend'
```

Now, the attend method is executed when you click the button. Once you do that, you execute something like :

```
def attend
  event = Event.find(params[:id])
  current_user.events << event
end
```

Comment: but i'm not trying to create a new event...i'm trying to associate the current_user with the event that is already created and displayed on the event#view page. Does this accomplish that?

Comment: i'm still a little confused. where does your code use the attend method from the user model? also, what would the "your_path" be? sorry, i'm a newb.

Comment: the attend method you specified goes in the user model right? not the users controller?

Comment: It actually goes to a controller and ideally the event controller. That is, because the resource we are talking about is the event(attend an event). It's another action, like new or create.

Comment: I did that like you said but I get "Couldn't find Event without an ID"

here's what I used:


<%= button_to 'Attend Event', attend_path, :id => :id, :method => :post %>

Comment: `attend_path` should take event's `id` (preferably it should be another action on resource member, not collection), because on Rails side you don't know which button users clicked. You only know which route user came to, and this route (or request body) should contain all necessary informations.

Comment: ok...also tried:

<%= button_to 'Attend Event', attend_path, :id => @event.id, :method => :post %>

and i still get the same issue..

Comment: In the action that renders the button_to, you have to define @event. Have you ?

Comment: I have @event defined on the show page (which is where the button_to is so it should be passing the @event.id correctly). then in the attend action I have @event = Event.find(params[:id]). is that what you meaN?

Comment: Yes, that sounds ok, make sure that the id specified in button_to is like ':id => @event.id'

Comment: yes, that is what I have...but still running into the same problem. MBO's answer below is slightly different, could that be the issue?

Comment: Sorry for all the questions...but why would MBO's answer be different from passing ":id => @event.id" ? what is incorrect about doing it this way?

Comment: MBO's passing is used with a GET method, like a link_to, my passing is used in a POST method, when :method => :post is defined.

Comment: this might be a dumb question but...isn't MBO's version using POST as well? I see POST in the button_to action